# AWS Quicksight - question about creating a calculated field using if else and custom aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-quicksight

I have a data that looks like this

| Date | Name | SurveyID | Score | Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-17 | Jack | 10 | 95 | Name |
| 2022-02-17 | Jack | 10 | 95 | Address |
| 2022-02-16 | Tom | 9 | 100 |  |
| 2022-02-16 | Carl | 8 | 93 | Zip |
| 2022-02-16 | Carl | 8 | 93 | Email |
| 2022-02-15 | Dan | 7 | 72 | Zip |
| 2022-02-15 | Dan | 7 | 72 | Email |
| 2022-02-15 | Dan | 7 | 72 | Name |
| 2022-02-15 | Dan | 6 | 90 | Phone |
| 2022-02-14 | Tom | 5 | 98 | Gender |

I wanted to have a segmentation data using the avg. score per individual.

```
Segment
A:  98%-100%
B:  95%-97%
C:  90%-94%
D:  80%-89%
E:  0% -79%
```

I did an if else formula which is this:

```
ifelse(Score} >= 98,'A',ifelse({Score} >= 95,'B',ifelse({Score} >= 90,'C',ifelse({Score} >= 80,'D','E'))))
```

This is now the output of what I did:

| Date | Name | SurveyID | Score | Error | Segement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-17 | Jack | 10 | 95 | Name | B |
| 2022-02-17 | Jack | 10 | 95 | Address | B |
| 2022-02-16 | Tom | 9 | 100 |  | A |
| 2022-02-16 | Carl | 8 | 93 | Zip | C |
| 2022-02-16 | Carl | 8 | 93 | Email | C |
| 2022-02-15 | Dan | 7 | 72 | Zip | E |
| 2022-02-15 | Dan | 7 | 72 | Email | E |
| 2022-02-15 | Dan | 7 | 72 | Name | E |
| 2022-02-15 | Dan | 6 | 90 | Phone | C |
| 2022-02-14 | Tom | 5 | 98 | Gender | A |

I realized that the calculation I did only applies for the score. I was expecting an output like this:

| Name | Average Score | Total Survey | Segement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 95 | 1 | B |
| Tom | 99 | 2 | A |
| Carl | 93 | 1 | C |
| Dan | 81 | 2 | D |

I have tried to create another calculated field for Average Score which is:

```
avgOver({Score}, [Name], PRE_AGG)
```

I believe I am missing a distinct count of survey IDs in that formula, that I do not know where to place. As for segmentation calculation, I cannot on my life figure that part out without getting aggregation errors on Quicksight. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from Quicksight Community. Pasting it here.

For segmentation, you can use the calculated field which you created for average score .

```
avg_score = avgOver(Score,[Name],PRE_AGG)
```

Segment

```
ifelse
(
    {avg_score}>= 98,'A',
    {avg_score}>= 95,'B',
    {avg_score}>= 90,'C',
    {avg_score}>= 80,'D',
    'E'
)
```

The survey id can be used to get the distinct count per individual.